# excel has stopped working corrupt workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

As I was working on a complex workbook (formatting, thousands of lines of code, etc), it suddenly stopped working.  Any attempt to open this file, including in safe mode results in "Excel has stopped working" error, immediately after the file opens.  All addins have been disabled, other workbooks open fine.  Can this file be saved?  I have lost two days of work, but it is two very progressive days.  Is there any hope?  If not, I gotta start again now, a task that I do not relish in any way.

Comment: update... I opened the file on my Mac as Read-only.  I'm not sure what that means or what my next step is, but its good to know that I can reference the GUI visually if necessary.  I hope this helps towards a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

I have somehow miraculously fixed this.  I opened the file on my MacBook, but there was a message about some things aren't going to work; read-only.  And if I saved it some things wouldn't work.  I ended up with 2 files; a 5Mb file and a 6Mb file.  I certainly assumed that the smaller one was the one that was going to be missing important components, but the larger one didn't open and the smaller one did and the file seems to be fully intact and I haven't found anything that doesn't work, including the very latest stuff that I had been working on.  Now that I've saved it a few times, using multiple filenames, the filesize is back to 6Mb.  If anyone can explain all this, I am eager to learn, but the best news is that I am back to life.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have published an article that explains several methods for recovering files:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153A45F4-6CAB-44B1-93CA-801DDCD4EA53

I find the method that works the most for me is simply to turn calculation to manual before I open the workbook.